# Python 3 Pandas: Counting entries in a column with the same occurance

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe which consists of a column with names:

Name
0  Mikaela
1  Anna
2  Hadley
3  Emma
4  Angie
...etc

How can I get the amounth of names, which occure only a specific time. E.g. How many names occure only once in this list?

Furthermore, whats an easy way to get the name with the greatest occurrences? I used `df['Name'].value_counts()` which gives me an overview over the names with the least and with the most occurences, but there must be a way to get only the one way with the highest occurance.

Comment: use `df.groupby('Name').count()`